# Question about pyobjects and id in python

Tags: python

```
f='a'.lower
b='a'.lower()
c='a'.lower()
d='a'

#RED
print(id(f))
print(id(b))                             -line  6 
print(id(c))                             -line  7
print(id('a'.lower))  

#YELLOW          
print(id('a'))
print(id(d)) 

#GREEN                           
print(id(f()))                          -line 11
print(id('a'.lower()))                  -line 12
```

The yellow and green portion outputs the same id respectively, each of the statement in red prints a different output.

1. Does b and c not reference to ‘a’? As is doesn’t seem that it is associated with the id of the pyobject of ‘a’.
2. Since line 11 and line 12 gives the same output, why are the outputs of line 6 VS line 7 VS line 11/12 different?

Comment: Every time you access a `.method`, you get a new unique bound method, so the method ids are all different. The method, when called, produces a new string. Small string literals may be interned and thus share one id. Memory is freed up when not needed, and thus two different values may share the same id as long as they don't exist at the same time. Feel free to apply these rules to your example to figure it out. Quite frankly, don't worry about it too much, it's irrelevant details, and has been asked in many permutations here many times…

Comment: To further expand on @deceze comment, I just entered `id('a'.lower())` three times in a row. The results were: `2449235336864`, `2449235271896`, `2449235336864`

Answer (score 0):

### id('a') == id(d) all others are different

| print | ids |
| --- | --- |
| print(id(f)) | 2074512186784 |
| print(id(b)) | 2074512260016 |
| print(id(c)) | 2074512260400 |
| print(id('a'.lower)) | 2074508806240 |
| print(id('a')) | 2076611140400 |
| print(id(d)) | 2076611140400 |
| print(id(f())) | 2074512260464 |
| print(id('a'.lower())) | 2074512260208 |

```
> python --version
Python 3.10.5
```